# php looping through 2D array

Tags: php

I access the following values like this.

```
$result->{'HistoricalPricesResult'}->HistoricalPricesResult[0]->Price
$result->{'HistoricalPricesResult'}->HistoricalPricesResult[0]->Low
//next row
$result->{'HistoricalPricesResult'}->HistoricalPricesResult[1]->Price
$result->{'HistoricalPricesResult'}->HistoricalPricesResult[1]->Low
```

However I need to consolidate this to

```
$values[0][price]
$values[0][low]
$values[1][price]
$values[1][low]
```

2 other strange things.  The values are strings and I need them to be decimals(2 decimal points) and also the min and the max for price and low accross all the rows

Answer (score 0):

Well the obvious way to build an array of values would be:

```
$values = array();
for($i = 0; $i < some_maximum_value; $i++) {
   $values[$i] = array(
      'price' => $result->{'HistoricalPricesResult'}->HistoricalPricesResult[$i]->Price,
      'low' => $result->{'HistoricalPricesResult'}->HistoricalPricesResult[$i]->Low,
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TADAAAAAA!!!!

```
$values = array();
foreach($result->{'HistoricalPricesResult'}->HistoricalPricesResult as $key => $obj){
    $values[$key]['price'] = $obj->Price;
    $values[$key]['low'] = $obj->low;
}
```

Comment: Now that you have the values, I'm pretty sure you can figure out how to find the min/max. That *is* what you're paid for anyway...

Answer (score 0):

```
$myVals = array();
foreach ($result->{'HistoricalPricesResult'}->HistoricalPricesResult as $key => $v)
{
   $myVals[$key]['price'] = 1.0 * $c->Price;  //hoping string has 2 after the decimal
   $myVals[$key]['low'] = 1.0 * $c->Low
}
```

Try to figure out max/min yourself

Check out foreach loops and string/float conversion

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion